# How, in R, to you pass parameters given in one tibble to perform operations on another?

Tags: r, apply, tibble

I'm looking to store some parameters in one tibble and use that information to aggregate the values associated with responsive rows from another dataset. So, in the sample setup below the return for p1 would be the sum value of all records in data_tibble where the number = 123, and the codes are either "code1" or "code2"*, and the date value equals 2020-01-01. And so on for p2.

I don't know how to do this; I've tried to create a function using apply and separately to simply create a function to run itself and produce a vector of results (as shown below in the doesnotwork function).

Any help appreciated!

Edited to fix a typo

*Here it's a bit silly, but I've got hundreds of different codes to deal with, and in some cases it will be easier to exclude all but a few, while in other cases it will be better just to include a handful, etc. So a NULL, or the ability to pass put in the list something that will cause all records to pass would be ideal.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#Set up Parameters
parameters_tibble <- tibble(name = character(),
                               number = numeric(),
                               acceptable_codes = list(),
                               unacceptable_codes = list(),
                               cutoff_date = date(),
                               .rows = NULL)
parameters_tibble$date <- as_date(parameters_tibble$date)

parameters_tibble <- add_row(parameters_tibble,
                             name = "param1",
                             number = 123,
                             acceptable_codes = list(c("code1", "code2")),
                             unacceptable_codes = list(NULL),
                             cutoff_date = as_date("2020-01-01"))

parameters_tibble <- add_row(parameters_tibble,
                             name = "param2",
                             number = 456,
                             acceptable_codes = list(NULL),
                             unacceptable_codes = list("code72"),
                             cutoff_date = as_date("2020-01-01"))

#Create sample dataset
data_tibble <- tibble(number = numeric(),
                      code = character(),
                      date = date(),
                      value = numeric(),
                      .rows=NULL)
data_tibble$date <- as_date(data_tibble$date)
data_tibble <- add_row(data_tibble,
                       number = rep(c(123,456),6),
                       code = rep(c("code1", "code2", "code3", "code4"),3),
                       date = as_date(rep(c("2020-01-01","2019-11-01"),6)),
                       value = rep(1:12))


doesnotwork <- function(dt = data_tibble, pt = parameters_tibble) {
  aggregatedValues <- dt %>% 
    sum(
      filter(number == pt$number &
               code %in% pt$acceptable_codes &
               !(code %in% pt$acceptable_codes) &
               date >= pt$cutoff_date) 
      $value)
  return(aggregatedValues)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew. Please make a reproducible example the next time, e.g. use columns which are present in your df's (`date` is no var in parameters_tibble, `Std.Amt` is no column in data_tibble). Based on your code and description my approach to computing the aggregated values uses `unnest` to get rid of the list columns (Note: It is sufficient to define the acceptable codes) and then uses a join + some additional filter statements to filter your data tibble according to the parameters tibble. After this step is is an easy task to compute the aggregated values. Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#Set up Parameters
parameters_tibble <- tibble(name = character(),
                            number = numeric(),
                            acceptable_codes = list(),
                            unacceptable_codes = list(),
                            cutoff_date = date(),
                            .rows = NULL)

parameters_tibble$cutoff_date <- as_date(parameters_tibble$cutoff_date)

parameters_tibble <- add_row(parameters_tibble,
                             name = "param1",
                             number = 123,
                             acceptable_codes = list(c("code1", "code2")),
                             unacceptable_codes = list(NULL),
                             cutoff_date = "2020-01-01")

parameters_tibble <- add_row(parameters_tibble,
                             name = "param2",
                             number = 456,
                             acceptable_codes = list(c("code1", "code2", "code3")),
                             unacceptable_codes = list("code4"),
                             cutoff_date = "2020-01-01")

# Unnest: One row for each acceptable code
parameters_tibble_unnest <- parameters_tibble %>% 
  unnest(c(acceptable_codes, unacceptable_codes))

#Create sample dataset
data_tibble <- tibble(number = numeric(),
                      code = character(),
                      date = date(),
                      value = numeric(),
                      .rows=NULL)

data_tibble$date <- as_date(data_tibble$date)

data_tibble <- add_row(data_tibble,
                       number = rep(c(123,456),6),
                       code = rep(c("code1", "code2", "code3", "code4"),3),
                       date = as_date(rep(c("2020-01-01","2019-11-01"),6)),
                       value = rep(1:12))

# Filter using joins
df_join <- left_join(data_tibble, parameters_tibble_unnest, by = c("number", "code" = "acceptable_codes")) %>% 
  # Drop non-matching data-rows with no match in acceptable codes
  filter(!is.na(name)) %>% 
  # filter for cutoff-date
  filter(date >= cutoff_date) %>% 
  # filter for unacceptable_codes
  filter(!code %in% unacceptable_codes)

df_join
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>   number code  date       value name   unacceptable_codes cutoff_date
#>    <dbl> <chr> <date>     <dbl> <chr>  <chr>              <date>     
#> 1    123 code1 2020-01-01     1 param1 <NA>               2020-01-01 
#> 2    123 code1 2020-01-01     5 param1 <NA>               2020-01-01 
#> 3    123 code1 2020-01-01     9 param1 <NA>               2020-01-01

aggregated_values <- df_join %>% 
  count(number, wt = value)
aggregated_values
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   number     n
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    123    15
```

## Update: Putting it in a function

```r
get_aggregated_values <- function(dt, pt) {
  # Unnest: One row for each acceptable and unacceptable code
  pt_unnest <- pt %>% 
    unnest(c(acceptable_codes, unacceptable_codes))

  # Join by number and code == acceptable_codes
  dt_join <- left_join(dt, pt_unnest, by = c("number", "code" = "acceptable_codes")) %>% 
    # Drop non-matching data-rows with no match in acceptable codes
    filter(!is.na(name)) %>% 
    # filter for cutoff-date
    filter(date >= cutoff_date) %>% 
    # filter for unacceptable_codes
    filter(!code %in% unacceptable_codes)

  aggregated_values <- dt_join %>% 
    count(number, wt = value)
  aggregated_values
}

get_aggregated_values(data_tibble, parameters_tibble)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   number     n
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    123    15
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Fixed my typos too, sorry about that. 
That's a good way to get p1, but I'll need to deal with dozens of parameter sets (maybe hundreds) so I'm hoping to get this set up in a way that can address each in turn. I guess I could just loop it, but had hoped for something else.

Also, I will need both the "acceptable_codes" and "unacceptable_codes"; I realize on that example data it didn't make sense, but I'll be dealing with hundreds of different and always growing sets of codes for different "numbers", so I'll need to be able to either pass all but a few, or only pass a few.

Comment: Hi. Okay. I see. Just edited my code to take account of the unacceptable codes. And simply put everything in a function which can be used to loop over data and parameter dfs. Check it out.